# JSON - simple get an Integer instead of Long

Tags: java, json, casting, integer, long-integer

How to get an `Integer` instead of `Long` from JSON?

I want to read JSON in my Java program, but when I get a JSON value which is a number, my parser returns a number of type `Long`.

I want to get an `Integer`. I tried to cast the long to an integer, but java throws a `ClassCastException` (`java.lang.Long` cannot be cast to `java.lang.Integer`).

I tried several things, such as first converting the long to a string, and then converting with `Integer.parseInt();` but also that doesn't work.

I am using [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Edit:

I still can't get it working. Here is an example:
jsonItem.get("amount"); // returns an Object

I can do this:

```
(long)jsonItem.get("amount");
```

But not this:

```
(int)jsonItem.get("amount");
```

I also can't convert it with

```
Integer newInt = new Integer(jsonItem.get("amount"));
```

or

```
Integer newInt = new Integer((long)jsonItem.get("amount"));
```

Comment: The `Long` object has an `intValue()` method.

Comment: Now it looks like you are deliberately trying to come up with each possible variation on the right solution that is not right. Why don't you just follow the example provided to you by either Hot Licks or Joop Eggen?

Comment: I got it working. Thanks. I was confused by the classes and data types

Comment: Listen carefully:  JSON is returning a `Long` *object*.  That object contains within it a `long` value.  If you want that value to be represented in an `Integer` object you must extract the value from the `Long` object and create a new `Integer` object from the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please understand that `Long` and `Integer` are object classes, while `long` and `int` are primitive data types.  You can freely cast between the latter (with possible loss of high-order bits), but you must do an actual conversion between the former.

```
Integer newInt = new Integer(oldLong.intValue());
```

Comment: `Integer.valueOf(oldLong.intValue())` would be preferred, or the equivalent, but less explicit `(int)(long)oldLong`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik -- Yeah, that would be better.

Comment: Per OP's first example, if the `(long)jsonItem.get("amount");` can be parsed as a long, why not a primitive int?

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
(int)(long)jsonItem.get("amount");
```

and it worked for me