# JSON Loading in Java: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, json

I'm trying out the example from [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/), and am using this code to write to a file:

```
    public void Write() {

        FileWriter file = null;
        try {
            JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("name", "mky4ong.com");
            obj.put("age", new Integer(100));
            JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
            obj2.put("name", "mk54yong.com");
            obj2.put("age", new Integer(1800));
            file = new FileWriter(filename);
            JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
            list.add(obj);
            list.add(obj2);

            o.put("messages", list);

            file.write(o.toJSONString());
            file.flush();
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {logger.error("{}", ex.getCause());} finally {try {file.close();} catch (IOException ex) {logger.info("{}",ex.getCause());}}   
}
```

and using this code to read from the same file:

```
public void Load() {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filename));
    } catch (IOException | ParseException ex) {logger.info("{}", ex.getCause());}
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONArray msg = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("messages");
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = msg.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject ob = iterator.next();
        String name =(String) ob.get("name");
        Integer age =(Integer) ob.get("age");
        logger.info("name: {}, age: {}", name, age);
    }
}
}
```

But although the data is written successfully as `{"messages":[{"name":"mky4ong.com","age":100},{"name":"mk54yong.com","age":1800}]}`, I have trouble while loading.
At this line `Integer age =(Integer) ob.get("age");` the compiler says "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer".

I tried casting in multiple ways, but it doesn't work. Why does such an error happen?

ps: I'm using `compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'`

Comment: in the example that _you_ linked, the author casts to `Long`, not `Integer`...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869138/json-simple-get-an-integer-instead-of-long for help. That question is about the same problem, though not exactly a duplicate imo.

Comment: json-simple states it maps numbers to some instance of `java.lang.Number`, so a proper "cast" might be `Number.class.cast(ob.get("age")).intValue()` (not tested)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write your json file all additional information is lost (in your case the `Integer` type you used. When you read it the JSONParser will automatically use `Long` when it encounters a number without decimal points. Try using `Long` in your reader. Note that the reader knows **nothing** about the writer. It can only read a file and interpret it as it sees fit.

So to answer your question:

```
Long age =(Long) ob.get("age");
```

will work.

Comment: Ok this is very odd. I tried this in an earlier program, when loading just numbers from a JSON array, and the cast to long didn't work. Thanks though!